# How do I select objects in Render view?

Tags: palette, magicavoxel

I'm trying to select a single 1x1 cube to have it emit light (like a lamp), but I'm confused trying to figure out how to select it while in Render mode. I've tried selecting it while in Model, then switching to Render view and editing the material, but it winds up changing the wrong objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else with this same question the simplest answer I've found is that you use the palettes on the left as not just colors but as individual materials. When you select that color/material while in render mode and make changes to it's material every single object in the render with that color/material will take on those new properties.

Answer (score 1):

In Magica Voxel, properties of a material are for all elements using that material - there aren't "Item Shaders" as there are in larger **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) tools such as modo, maya, 3DS, Blender or C4D; as a result, to set a given item to "glow", you need to assign it a unique material and set that material's property to emit light.